# コントローラから値が取れなくこまってます。

Tags: thymeleaf

プログラミング初心者です。

コントローラから値がうけとれません。コントローラからの値を変えても、結果は変わりなく判定もされないので、switch文がコントローラと連携が取れていない気がしますが、どうしたらいいのかわかりません。教えて頂きたいです。

```html
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="User:${userList}">
        <td class="text-center">
            <div th:switch="${User.plan}">
                <p th:case="'plann'">準備中</p>
            </div>

            <div th:case="'Save'">
                <a href="" '>保存</a>
            </div>

            <div th:case="'Submit'">
                <a href="">提出</a>
            </div>

            <div th:case="'Cancel'">
                <a href="">キャンセル</a>
            </div>

            <div th:case="*">
                <a href="">参照</a>
            </div>               -->   
        </td>
<tbody>
```

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping(value = "user")

    public String User(Model Model) {

        List<User> pro= new ArrayList<User>();

        Mission P = new Mission();

        Model.addAttribute("userList",P);

        return "userList.html";
    }

}

package com.example.demo;

public class User {

    private String plan; 

    public User() {
        this.plan = "Submit";
    }

    public String getplan() {
        return MissionSt;
    }

    public void setplan(String missionSt) {
        MissionSt = missionSt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

いろいろと間違っていますが、1番正しくないのは`userList.html`が想定しているユーザーのリスト（`ArrayList<User>`オブジェクト）ではなく、`Mission`オブジェクトを`Model.addAttribute()`に渡していることです。

```java
Model.addAttribute("userList",P);
```

少なくとも、以下です。

```java
Model.addAttribute("userList",pro);
```

ただし、このように修正しても`pro`は要素数がゼロの配列なので、htmlには何も表示されません。少なくとも`pro.add(･･･);`の1行が必要です。

それからぱっと見の指摘ですが、

- `th:switch`のタグが並列関係になっていない
- `<tbody>`タグ、`<tr>`タグがクローズされていない
- `<a href="" '>`のシングルクォーテーションは不要
- `Mission`と`plan`がごちゃごちゃになっている
- メソッド名は`getplan()`、`setplan()`ではなく、`getPlan()`、`setPlan()`
- 変数名が分かりにくい（`List<User> pro= new ArrayList<User>();`）。なぜユーザーのリストが`pro`？
- 変数名の先頭が大文字になっている（`Mission P = new Mission();`）。通常小文字で始めます。

などを修正する必要がありそうです。

Comment: たくさん教えて頂いて有難うございます。順番に修正してみます。

Comment: 改めてちょっと調べてみたら、`<p th:case="'･･･'">`のシングルクォーテーションは必要かもしれません。